# Extracting ranked values from different rows - SQL

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a database with various categories. For each category I have three quantities, and I want to extract a row containing the 25th largest value from each of the quantities per category (ties can be safely ignored).

For example, I might have a database whose rows were towns or cities from one of several countries. The categories are countries, and the quantities might be population, land area, and latitude. The data would then look something like:

```
TownName    Country    Population    LandArea    Latitude
Paris       France     500,715       47.9        45.76
Manchester  USA        110,229       90.6        42.99
Calais      France     72,589        33.5        50.95
Leicester   England    337,653       73.3        52.63
Dunkirk     France     90,995        43.9        51.04
...         ...        ...           ...         ...
```

In this example, the end result I'd want would be each of the countries in the list, along with their 25th largest population, 25th largest land area and 25th largest latitude. This no longer resembles some specific town or city, but gives some information about each country. This might look like:

```
Country    Population    LandArea    Latitude
France     144,548       83.95       50.21
Poland     141,080       88.3        54.17
Australia  68,572        146         -21.35
...        ...           ...         ...
```

I've figured out one way to do this, which was to do the following:

1. Use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to rank one of Population, LandArea and Latitude in descending order, partitioned over countries.
2. Repeat this three times (one for each quantity), and `JOIN` the three databases together. In the `ON` statement, ensure the values of the Country columns are equal, as are the values of the rank columns.
3. Use a `WHERE` statement to pull out the row for each country with rank 25.

I don't like this method because it involved creating three almost exact copies of decent sized chunks of code to get three separate databases I joined together (each of the blocks of code in the join statments were a decent size because this is a simplified example, and I had to do other stuff to get to a stage like this).

I was wondering whether there was a way which wouldn't involve me repeating large chunks of code with a `JOIN` statement as this makes my code big and ugly. Also, this seems like something which may crop up time and time again, so a more efficient method would be wonderful.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Use three separate analytical expressions with different `ORDER BY` in the same query?

Comment: Perhaps. I tried something like that before, and couldn't get it to work, but that sounds promising, so I'm giving it another go now (I'm pretty new to SQL so it's entirely possible I missed something fairly obvious)

Comment: @PM77-1 I tried:
SELECT Country,
    (SELECT TOP 25 Population ORDER BY PopulationRank),
    (SELECT TOP 25 LandArea ORDER BY AreaRank),
    (SELECT TOP 25 Latitude ORDER BY LatRank)
  FROM [code for data with ranks already done]
  GROUP BY Country
But I don't think that's giving me the right sort of thing, even if I could cut it down (I tried a WHERE clause, but that was no good; I think I understand why). Maybe you were thinking of something along different lines and I misunderstood?
I'm gonna return to this tomorrow. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: My suggestion was to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you can't find a way to eliminate the 3-join approach, you can simplify the join condition by assigning each distinct tuple a `GroupID`:

```
;WITH
    MasterCTE AS
    (
        SELECT      *,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Country) AS GroupID -- Don't use ROW_NUMBER here. RANK or DEMSE_RANK only
        FROM        MyTable
    ),
    cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT      GroupID, [Population],
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY [Population] DESC) AS PopulationRank
        FROM        MasterCTE
    ),
    cte2 AS
    (
        SELECT      GroupID, LandArea,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY LandArea DESC) AS LandAreaRank
        FROM        MasterCTE
    ),
    cte3 AS
    (
        SELECT      GroupID, Latitude,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY Latitude DESC) AS LatitudeRank
        FROM        MasterCTE
    )


SELECT DISTINCT  -- Remember to include DISTINCT
            MasterCTE.Country,
            cte1.Population, cte2.LandArea, cte3.Latitude
FROM        MasterCTE   
INNER JOIN  cte1        ON MasterCTE.GroupID = cte1.GroupID AND cte1.PopulationRank = 25
INNER JOIN  cte2        ON MasterCTE.GroupID = cte2.GroupID AND cte2.LandAreaRank   = 25
INNER JOIN  cte3        ON MasterCTE.GroupID = cte3.GroupID AND cte3.LatitudeRank   = 25
```